# Sort string and number combination in descending in oralce

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a combination of string and number in descending order .

Input :

```
P9S1
P7S1
P13S1
P12S2
P10S1
```

Expected output:

```
P13S1
P12S2
P10S1
P9S1
P7S1
```

Here is what I tried

Sample code:

```
  with
      inputs (firmware) as (
        select 'P9S1'  from dual union all
        select 'P7S1' from dual union all
        select 'P13S1' from dual union all
        select 'P12S2' from dual union all
        select 'P10S1'      from dual
      )
    select firmware
    from   inputs
    order by 
    regexp_replace(firmware, '\d+\.\d+') desc ;
```

But this doesn't work as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the input always made up of "string of letters" (at least one letter), then "string of digits", then (optionally) more alternating strings of "letters" and strings of "digits"? Then - **how** do you need to order them? Is the first part always the single letter `P`, or can it be anything else? Then, it seems you must order descending by the first group of digits (treated as integers). If there are still ties, then what? Don't just show one small example and expect that it will illustrate all the possible special cases that may occur in your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not actually explain how the strings should turned to numbers.

This would work for your dataset:

```
order by to_number(regexp_replace(firmware, '\D', '')) desc
```

The idea is to remove all non-digits characters from the string, turn the resulting string to a number, and use it for sorting.

```
with inputs (firmware) as (
    select 'P9S1' from dual union all
    select 'P7S1' from dual union all
    select 'P13S1' from dual union all
    select 'P12S2' from dual union all
    select 'P10S1' from dual
)
select firmware
from   inputs
order by to_number(regexp_replace(firmware, '\D', '')) desc ;
```

```
| FIRMWARE |
| :------- |
| P13S1    |
| P12S2    |
| P10S1    |
| P9S1     |
| P7S1     |
```

Comment: The string always remains "P" and "S" so it doesn't matter. This works great, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks much for the quick reply.